# Global Dictionary/Scope Issue

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I've defined a global dictionary, and I want to add to it within a MySQL connection block. Problem is, once outside of that block, the dictionary appears empty. This feels like a basic scope problem, but it seems odd that things added to the dictionary won't stay put, no?

Code:

```
var express = require("express");
var http = require("http");
var mysql = require("mysql");

objects = {};

getBiz = function() {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host:"localhost",
        user:"APIUser",
        password:"password"
    });

    connection.query("USE biz");
    var bizQuery = "SELECT * FROM biz";
    var bizObjects = [];
    connection.query(bizQuery, function(err, bizRows) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            for (bizRow in bizRows) {
                var bizObject = {};
                bizObject['id'] = bizRows[bizRow]['id'];
                bizObject['biz_name'] = bizRows[bizRow]['biz_name'];
                bizObjects.push(bizObject);
            }
        }
        objects['biz'] = bizObjects;
        console.log(objects); // prints the objects
    });
    console.log(objects); // prints {}
};

var app = express();

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.send(getBiz());
});

var server = app.listen(8888, function() {
    console.log("Listening........");
});
```

Comment: Maybe your outer object never get populated because the callback for your mysql query never got called at the time you printed out the object to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is synchronous in style when it should be asynchrounous. ***use callbacks***

```
getBiz = function(onGetObjects) {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host:"localhost",
        user:"APIUser",
        password:"password"
    });

    connection.query("USE biz");
    var bizQuery = "SELECT * FROM biz";
    var bizObjects = [];
    connection.query(bizQuery, function(err, bizRows) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            for (bizRow in bizRows) {
                var bizObject = {};
                bizObject['id'] = bizRows[bizRow]['id'];
                bizObject['biz_name'] = bizRows[bizRow]['biz_name'];
                bizObjects.push(bizObject);
            }
        }
        objects['biz'] = bizObjects;
        onGetObjects(objects); // prints the objects
    });
    console.log(objects); //will definitely print {}
};

function onGetObjects(obj){
   this.objects = obj;
    console.log(objects) // should give you the correct objects
}

var app = express();

//pass in the callback
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
   res.send(getBiz(onGetObjects));
});

var server = app.listen(8888, function() {
   console.log("Listening........");
});
```